# Combining =IF and =RIGHT in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to calculate a Win/Loss formula based on two other cells but it wont work correctly. I attached what I currently have and I do not understand why it wont work.

For betting, I bet on the over (the o in o2.5) 2.5 so if the result is 4, it wins, and should say W. But incorrectly says L.

Any suggestions on how to get this to work?

Thank you in advance!

[Google Sheets Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV7i0.png)

Answer (score 2):

You just have a little mistake. What the screenshot shows is the following.

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bet line | Result | W/L |
| 2 | o2.5 | 4 | L |
| 3 | o2.5 | 1 | L |

A and B were columns filled with data. Let me firstly mention that the data collection is a bit weird and your over and under would be better just initially be put in an extra column.

In cell C2, the code used was:

```
=IF(B2>RIGHT(A2,3), "W", "L")
```

The problem here is that column A now is in a text/string format due to the "o". Your IF() comparison now compares a float (number) to text (string) and it was apparently arbitrarily designated that the float is smaller. I reversed the order of the input and it will actually give the opposite result.

You just have to convert your string to a float, done by the VALUE() function.

```
=IF(B2>VALUE(RIGHT(A2,3)), "W", "L")
```

This correctly gives:

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Bet line | Result | W/L |
| 2 | o2.5 | 4 | W |
| 3 | o2.5 | 1 | L |

Good luck with your Gsheets adventure!